# NETBIOS over wifi does not see the ethernet machines in the same subnet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, netbios

Subnet 192.168.0.* has fifteen NETBIOS-capable devices, all on the same workgroup name.  The devices are a mix of Windows, Ubuntu, and Zorin (reskinned Ubuntu), and a network printer.  Several of the systems are dual-boot Windows and Ubuntu.  All is well among the ethernet connections.

For cabling reasons, I would like some of the wifi-capable machines to come off of ethernet.  Wifi works on those machines to the extent of having internet access, but none can resolve NETBIOS names when on wifi.  Those same machines are OK when cabled.

Router is a Motorola MG8702.  The router is connected to three unmanaged gigabyte switches which distribute ethernet around the place.  Wifi reception is excellent overall.  Wifi is on the same router on the same subnet.  All machines are DHCP clients, no fixed IP addresses.  A dedicated DNS server is impractical here.

What am I missing?

Comment: sounds like you have AP/Client Isolation turned on in your wifi AP, rather than an issue with name resolution. AP Isolation a feature designed for installations where systems don't need to see each other (like coffee shops) to prevent users from trying to hack one another. you can check to see whether its name res vs isolation by trying to connect by IP instead of name.

Comment: Do other local name resolution mechanisms (mDNS, LLMNR) work better? Do WiFi-connected devices receive the NetBIOS packets through wlan0? Are there any multicast-related settings on the WiFi AP?

Comment: Are the Wifi adapters defined with the same attributes as the ethernet ones?

Comment: In trying to answer the questions in the three comments above, I found the problem is deep in Windows networking on a per-machine basis.  The wireless machines are all Ubuntu.  All Ubuntu machines, wired or not can see each other by name.  At the moment, there is no point trying to answer or comment.

Comment: It is quite likely this question no longer makes sense.  I will ask a different, better focused questioin later, if necessary.  Frank Thomas Client isolation was and is off.  user1686 I have no idea about mDNS or LLMNR.  I will have to research those.  barrymc I have no idea which attributes you mean, but I have not tinkered with anything.  Thise settings are the way the operating system installer left them.

Answer (score 0):

Three part solutiion:

1. On Ubuntu: sudo apt install avahi-daemon  (no config, it just works)
2. On Windows: install mDNS https://skjoldtech.wordpress.com/2019/07/14/access-linux-machine-with-mdns-hostname-in-windows/
3. On the router (Motorola MG8702) I had certain Windows systems blocked from the internet by MAC address.  Apparently the ethernet side of the router thinks the wifi side is on the internet, even though it's all 192.168.0.*.  I removed the block in the router configuration, and it works.

@user1686, your mention of mDNS was the key.  Thanks.